Expressing the angle of a right triangle using the angles of neighbouring triangles
I'm trying to solve a simple one-dimensional calibration problem. Suppose you use a compass and have a screen placed somewhere in space and you measure the angle from the North pole to left and right edges of the 1D-screen as well as the middle. I'm trying to map the angle readings of the compass to a discrete pointer on the screen. This can then be easily generalised to 2D, if one uses an AHRS.
This problem can be modelled mathematically as shown in the figure:
A right right triangle is given, which is then split into three smaller triangles, their angles being $\theta_1, \theta_2, \theta_3$ and the opposite sides $c_1, c_2, c_3$
The screen is represented with $c_2, c_3$, it holds that $c_2=c_3$ and the screen width is given by $c_2+c_3$, we can then measure the angles to the north pole at the edges of the screen and the middle and can obtain $\theta_2, \theta_3$ (simply by subtracting the left measurement from the right one). We however don't know $\theta_1$ or $c_1$ - since the screen could be placed anywhere. The question now is: How can we express $\theta_1$ knowing only $\theta_2, \theta_3, c_2, c_3$?
Thanks to M.Riyan I know that the problem is solvable, but I have issues solving this problem and his hint to use the sine-rule is still puzzling to me - how does one obtain this equation?
$$ \frac{\sin(\theta_2)}{\sin(\theta_3)}=\frac{\sin(\theta_1)}{\sin(\theta_1+\theta_2)}$$
I was thinking of using the law of cosines for triangles and then trying to get rid of the terms which we don't know, but with little success
EDIT: Improved the question, added the motivation and my attempts and improved the figure.

Tell us what you have tried...

Hint: It is solvable...

That's great! I honestly haven't tried anything because I didn't know if it was solvable, but I'll try now

Do I know the value of $c1$? Or do I just know that $c1=c2$?

Another hint, apply sine-rule of triangle to both of the triangles at the right, you should have something like this:
$$
\frac{\sin\theta_1}{\sin\theta_2}=\frac{\cos\theta}{\cos(\theta+\theta_1)}
$$

Try finding $\theta$ from the above equation, if you are struck, add you works in the question. I have considered $\theta_i$ as $\theta_1$ and $\theta_j$ as $\theta_2$. Hope that does not bother you....

The only thing we know is that c1=c2. That's great! Thank you for the hint @M.Riyan

I'm still stuck, @M.Riyan how did you obtain the equation? Also I rewrote the question, so it is more readable now and changed the variable names, so that they are more intuitive.

This https://i.sstatic.net/bm54y7cU.jpg explains everything....

@M.Riyan I now obtain the equation $\frac{c_2}{c_3 \sin{\theta_2} \sin{\theta_3}} = \frac{\cos{(\theta_1+\theta_2)}}{cos({\theta_1})}$, is this a correct derivation? And also how does one express $\theta_1$ from $\frac{\cos{(\theta_1+\theta_2)}}{cos({\theta_1})}$?

As you have found:
$$\frac{c_2}{c_3 \sin\theta_2\sin\theta_3}=\frac{\cos(\theta_1+\theta_2)}{\cos\theta_1}$$
I have not checked whether this derivation is correct, but I can help you with the simplification.
Just consider the right hand side:
$$\frac{\cos\theta_1\cos\theta_2-\sin\theta_1\sin\theta_2}{\cos\theta_1}$$
$$\cos\theta_2-\tan\theta_1\sin\theta_2$$
Since everything on the L.H.S. is constant and therefore known, consider that to be $k$, then:
$$k=cos\theta_2-\tan\theta_1\sin\theta_2$$
$$\tan\theta_1=\frac{\cos\theta_2-k}{\sin\theta_2}$$
$$\theta_1=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\cos\theta_2-k}{\sin\theta_2}\right)$$
Moreover as $c_2=c_3$, then $k$ can be written as:
$$\theta_1=
\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\cos\theta_2-\frac{1}{\sin\theta_2\sin\theta_3}}{\sin\theta_2}\right)$$
$$
\theta_1=
\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\cos\theta_2\sin\theta_2\sin\theta_3-1}{\sin^2\theta_2\sin\theta_3}\right)
$$
Your derivation seems to be correct, since as $\theta_2\rightarrow0^\circ$, $\theta_1\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{2}$, which seems reasonable.

Do not forget to upvote and accept this as an answer if you find this helpful. Any kind of suggestions or questions are always welcome.

Excellent! Thank you much!

Do I deserve an upvote, if you have liked it....?

You absolutely deserve an upvote, I'm very thankful for the answer, but I sadly cannot upvote as I don't have sufficient reputation.
